# Spring MVC output CSV to highcharts

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, csv, highcharts

I am trying to populate highcharts chart using a csv file that I will generate in java back end and send to the from end using spring mvc.

First my controller class which I am almost positive is the issue but I don't know how to correctly send the csv file:

```
@Controller
public class ChartController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/index", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String indexHandler() {
        return "index";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/out", method = GET)
    public String chartHandler() {
        String fileName = "test.csv" //note: I have also tried moving this 
                                     //file to my WEB-INF location and it doesn't make a difference
        InputParser input = new InputParser();

        for (GenericDataObject gdo : input.getDataObjects()) {
            CSVOutput.writeCSV(fileName,gdo);
        }

      return "index";
    }

}
```

The csv file is successfully created as I intend so that's not an issue

here is my Java script for highcharts

```
<html>
<head>
<script
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

 <some more high charts for font and color that I will leave out because its not currently being used>

</head>
<body>

      <div id='container' style="width: 100%; height: 600px;"></div>

      <script type="text/javascript">

      $(document)ready.function() {
          var groupId = [];
          var date = [];
          var val = [];
          var options = {

             chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                type: 'line'
              },
              title: {
                  text: 'test'
              },
              xAxis: {
                 title: {
                    text: 'group and date'
                 },
                 categories: [groupId, date]
              },
              yAxis: {
                  title:  {
                      text: 'data'
                  }
               },
              series: [{
                  data: val
               }]
            };

           $.get('http://localhost:8080/web-data-app/out', function(data)) {
                 alert("success");
                 var lines = data.split('\n')
                 $.each(lines, function(lineNo, line) {
                    var items = line.split(',');
                    groupId.push(items[1]);
                    date.push(items[2]);
                    val.push(items[4]);
                   });
                   var cahrt = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
               });
           });
     </script>
     </body>
     </html>
```

As of right now I get the outline of highcharts in my container, as well as the success alert so i know that much is working. however no data is being displaying withing the chart.

Answer (score 0):

You can use httpResponse and send your content there. Like this

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/out", method = GET)
public void chartHandler(HttpServletResponse httpResponse) {
    String fileName = "test.csv" //note: I have also tried moving this 
                                 //file to my WEB-INF location and it doesn't make a difference
    InputParser input = new InputParser();

    for (GenericDataObject gdo : input.getDataObjects()) {
        CSVOutput.writeCSV(fileName,gdo);
    }
   httpResponse.setContentType("text/csv");
   //you can use the output stream below to pass your content
   httpResponse.getOutputStream()

}
```